# How to connect to DB2 Database from a non-DB2 system using vba with out DB2 native driver

Tags: database, windows, vba, driver, db2-luw

I would like to know how can I connect to DB2 database on a remote server from my machine which does not have db2.
I know that if I have db2 installed on my local system I can make use of the native DB2 OLEDB/ODBC drive to connect to the DB2 database on remote server.

Comment: You might check this page www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: Hi Biplob, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please add what you have tried so far? Have you had any difficulties?

Comment: I want my application to connect to DB2 server with having a DB2 copy at my PC. Is this possible? I could connect to DB2 Database residing on a remote server using DB2 ODBC / OLE DB Driver. But I a user does not have db2 installed on his/her machine how can he/she connect to that DB?

Comment: I am currently connecting to teh remote DB using the following code:

Comment: I am currently connecting to teh remote DB using the following code:
Function connect_DB() As ADODB.Connection
Dim ConnectString As String
ConnectString = "Provider=IBMDADB2;Database=XXXX;hostname=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;port=5XXXX ;protocol=TCPIP; uid=XXXXX; pwd=XXXX"
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.CursorLocation = adUseClient
con.Open ConnectString
Set dbConnPublic = con
Set con = Nothing
End Function

Comment: Here I am using DB2 native drive for conencting to the remote DB. But if I dont have db2 installed on my PC how can I connect to the remote db? Is there any code or native driver which supports db connectivity between client and remote db server and does not require db2 to be there at client?

Comment: So, you want a DB2 driver without installing a DB2 driver?

Comment: Yes either a Driver through which I can connect to DB2 remote DB or the code snippet through which I can connect

Comment: You cannot have a driver without a driver, and no code snippet can help. You need to install a DB2 client package.

Comment: Can I connect via JDBC driver..Is there any native driver which can connect to db2 without a DB2 copy at the client? My requirement is that I am building tool which will be installed at the client machine and will connect to DB2 remote DB and get the details of the DB. the client machine ma/may not have db2 client.

Answer (score 0):

Even with JDBC you would still need (as for any DMBS) the DB2 JDBC driver installed. 
You will always need one of the clients installed:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/c0022612.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-0-2-0&lang=en

In particular you are probably looking for the "IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI" which is "... a lightweight solution that is designed for ISV deployments. This driver, also referred to as the CLI driver, provides runtime support for applications using the ODBC API or CLI API, without the need to install the Data Server Client or the Data Server Runtime Client. "